# Restrict editing of a part of the document in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have a content section that i wish to restrict the editing of. However, i am unable to accomplish this. My workflow is as follows: Select the content, Go to Review and then click on Restrict Editing. In the Editing restrictions option, i select No changes (read only) option. And then click on Start Enforcing Protection.

However, the problem that i am facing is that the entire document is getting restricted for editing. Also, it would be worthwhile to mention that the content i wish to restrict editing to is in a different section.

Answer (score 1):

Change your option from "No changes (read only)" to "Filling in forms".

Then you'll get an option below "Select sections..." and you can choose which sections are restricted.  Because your protected section will have no form fields, it'll "lock" the entire section from editing which is what you want to achieve.

In the screenshot below, I've protected section 2 (so rest of document - unticked sections - can be edited).

[image]

Comment: This was great for me. I replaced the page break between the cover page and the second page with a "Section Break, next page" (Find it under Layout, Page Setup, Breaks). No I can allow editing of the cover page while keeping the rest of the doc limited to text entry! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/508-word-lock-parts-of-document.html

1. Select the content you want to restrict
2. Go to `Developer Tab`, and select `Rich Text Content Control`
3. Then go to `Properties` in `Developer tab` , give a `tittle` and tick `Content control cannot be deleted` and `Contents cannot be edited`.
4. Then go to `Restrict Editing Tab`

There select `Limit formatting to a selection of style`
Untick `Allow only this type of editing in the document` option.

Then `start enforcing`